# why dynamic values are missing in emails?

Tags: email, email-template, apex-email-service

I have email one email template. In that email template I'm Passing dynamic values like {!Student.Name}. But when i receive email the student name is not displaying.

Here is my Html and Plain Text of emails:

[image]

Here is my email how i received with missing those dynamic data

[image]

Can anybody please tell me what could be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that you attach correct record to email template?

Comment: Yeah i am sure that attached correct record

Comment: please check fls

Comment: probably you just don't have field level access under user who sends email or there may be mistake in the template

Comment: I Invoked Apex class in process builder schedule actions. I passed the template id in apex class then will send emails. I am having this problem with process builder schedule actions. But I created Time based workflow for this and has given same template. I'm receiving emails with proper field values. What could be the problem with invoking apex class with process builder?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure, the record that you attached has lookup of "Certification" Object?
If not.

- The record you attached should have some link to that certification object, through lookup.
- Even after attaching the right record, you find it missing, then check for the permissions on that "Certification" Object and fields you have used.
- Make sure those objects and fields have enough permissions for current user to access them

Let me know if the problem still exists...

Comment: I Invoked Apex class in process builder schedule actions. I passed the template id in apex class then will send emails. I am having this problem with process builder schedule actions. But I created Time based workflow for this and has given same template. I'm receiving emails with proper field values. What could be the problem with invoking apex class with process builder?